# How would I use ellipses if I'm quoting some of a book?

Tags: quotations, ellipses

The whole passage:

> The most alarming of all man's assaults upon the environment is the contamination of air, earth, rivers,and sea with dangerous and even lethal materials. This pollution is for the most part irrecoverable; the chain of evil it initiates not only in the world that must support life but in living tissues is for the most part irreversible. in this now universal contamination of the environment, chemicals are the sinister and little-recognized partners of radiation in changing the very nature of the world-the very nature of life.

How would I quote it if I only want to use: "The most alarming of all man's assaults is contamination; pollution is irrecoverable, chemicals are sinister and little-recognized partners."?

Comment: You need to use more than that to properly retain the author's meaning; as alarmist as the original is, your abbreviated version is both more alarmist and less clear (what assaults are being considered, what are chemicals partners of?).

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, like this:
"The most alarming of all man's assaults ... is ... contamination .... pollution is ... irrecoverable..., chemicals are ... sinister and little-recognized partners ...."
But this reveals the horrific extent to which you are revising the author's original. Another way is:
"The most alarming of all man's assaults" is "contamination;" "pollution is ... irrecoverable;" ... "chemicals" are "sinister and little-recognized partners"...

Equally ugly. You don't really want to quote this passage, you want to say what it says in your own word